# Select Form with Data Attribute: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I have a number of forms each of which have a data attribute of `data-validate`.  I know that I can select those forms with the following query:  `document.querySelectorAll('form[data-validate]')`.

I have, however, a two-fold question.  First, how could I select those same forms using `document.forms`.  Secondly, is one method preferable over the other?  That is, does it make a difference whether or not I use `document.forms` or `document.querySelectorAll`?

Thanks.

Comment: `document.forms` and `document.querySelectorAll('form')` will return the same form elements in an iterable collection. However, the difference is that if you do `document.forms`, it will select **all `<form>` elements**, regardless of whether they have the `data-validate` attribute or not, while `document.querySelectorAll('form[data-validate]')` allows you to take advantage of the browser's built-in selector system to filter your collection.

Comment: You could use something like `Array.from(document.forms).filter(form => form.getAttribute('data-validate'))` but whether that's "better" is very much opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, how could I select those same forms using document.forms

`document.forms` only allows addressing a form by its index, name or id so, other than looping over all the values in `document.forms` and testing each one in turn to see if it has a `data-validate` attribute: You can't.

> Secondly, is one method preferable over the other?

Preference is a matter of opinion. (Although the one involving less code that leaves the filtering to native code would fit more criteria of "better").